# Weak stationarity of the stochastic process and the impact of the lagged white noise

Tags: time-series, self-study, stochastic-processes, stationarity

I am struggling with following exerises:

Consider following discrete-time stochastic processes $Y_t$:
$$Y_t=\frac {5}{3} Y_{t-1}-\frac{2} {3} Y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t$$
$$Y_t=1.3 Y_{t-1}-0.4 Y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t+0.5\epsilon_{t-1}$$

Where $\epsilon_t$ is a white noise process with variance $\sigma^2=1$

I would say that both processes are non stationary, as $E(Y_t)$ depends on $t$ and therefore is not constant.

Am I right?If so, can the stationarity be achieved by taking lags $Y_t-Y_{t-1}$? And what is the impact of lagged white noise?

Last, how can I compute the exact expression for $E(Y_t)$ and $V(Y_t)$

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Hint: $\frac 53 - \frac 23 = 1$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate But how did you find out that $Y_{t-1} = Y_{t-2}$?

Comment: I never said that $Y_{t-1}$ equals $Y_{t-2}$. But it _might_ be the case that $E[Y_{t-1}] = E[Y_{t-2}]$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate could you please explain that in more detail? This topic is new for me and unfortunately confusing

Comment: The expectation of a sum is the sum of the  expectations. So, $$E[Y_t] = \frac 53E[Y_{t-1}] - \frac 23E[Y_{t-2}] + E[\varepsilon_t]$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate I know this rule thank you. But why  $E[Y_{t-1}]=E[Y_{t-2}]$?